# How to do live streamimg using Azure services

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-media-services

**Problem:** Using OpenCV I am continuously capturing frames and performing some sort of manipulation. Using that manipulated frame I am trying to do live streaming using Azure services.

I go through the Microsoft docs but I didn't find out any relevant information to perform live streaming using the frame.

Comment: Azure Media Services requires an RTMP stream and has some suggestions/requirements on that stream as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/encode-recommended-on-premises-live-encoders#configuring-on-premises-live-encoder-settings.  To go from OpenCV to RTMP there are a number of libraries that you can find that rely on either FFMPEG or Gstreaming to do the format conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to use some Azure Service, Azure Media Services is the right one. I'm not sure what / where you were searching, but here's the official doc for it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-live-tutorial-with-api